# Disabling cache for TEXT tables

Tags: hsqldb

I'm trying to disable cache in HsqlDB 2.3.4 for TEXT tables so that queries against CSV files return the latest values instead of the cached values from hsqdb memory.

Setting `cache_rows=0` raises an IllegalArgumentException, and setting it to 1 appears to have no effect. The `cached_rows` setting is probably reset to either the default value (10000 rows) or minimum value (100 rows).

If disabling cache is not supported, is it possible to drop the given table cache or even database cache before the query is run? It appears that shutting down the database or dropping the entire schema is supported but it's not a workaround I'd like to implement.

EDIT 1. Sample Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String dir = args[0];
    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:" + dir + "");

    {
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.execute("DROP TABLE books IF EXISTS");
        st.close();
    }
    {
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.execute("CREATE TEXT TABLE books (Title varchar(64), Author varchar(64))");
        st.close();
    }
    {
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.execute("SET TABLE books SOURCE \"books.csv;ignore_first=true;cache_rows=1\"");
        st.close();
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        System.out.println("iteration: " + x);

            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM books");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " : " + rs.getString(2));
            }
            st.close();
            Thread.sleep(15000L);
            //data from files is cached, results shows original rows
            //even after the file was modified on the file system

        //need to execute source off/on to reload the data from files

    }

    conn.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The cache is for improved query speed and is not related to modified data.

You want to query a CSV file that is produced by an external program.

Connect to the file as read-only. When you want to get the updated version of the file, use this to reload the data

```
SET TABLE XXX SOURCE OFF
SET TABLE XXX SOURCE ON
```

Comment: Yes, setting SOURCE OFF/ON reloads the data from files. Without these commands the resultset keeps returning original values even if the file is modified.